# Domain Driven Design - where should I put this kind of struct?

Tags: domain-driven-design

for example:

```
type AParams struct {
   a int
   b string
   c []anotherStruct
   ...
}
```

```
//domain/repo/a_repo.go
type ARepo interface {
    GetA(params Aparams, ...) (entity.A, error)
}
```

```
/// infra/repo/a_repo.go
//the implementation of ARepo interface goes here
...
```

My question is which layer should I put AParams struct to? And what is it called in DDD? Thanks.

In my opinion, it can be in infra layer coz the domain layer can call it in A repository interface

Comment: Architecture isn't a set of hard and fast rules.  Put the struct where it makes the most sense for your application.

Comment: AParams represents parameters to the GetA method, and thus it's very closely related to that method, and by extension, to the ARepo interface (in fact, you can think of it as being a part of the interface in a broather sense). Put it in the same layer/component as the ARepo interface (you can even put it in the same file if you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user-defined type that gets used as a parameter in an interface and that is only meaningful in conjunction with that interface (like your `Aparams`) should be declared in the same file/module as the interface.

That ensures on the one hand that there is only one definition of the type, regardless of how many implementations of the interface you get and on the other hand that users of the interface don't get an additional dependency on a particular implementation just so they can call the methods.